# Finding intersection between two collections in MongoDb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js

I have two very large(30000+ documents) collections, one contains words extracted from a text file(collection name 'word') and one contains words from a dictionary(collection name 'dictionary').

How can I get the words that exist in both collections?

(I've simplified the situation, documents inside the 'word' collection contain metadata about the words, so each word has to be a separate document.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy both collections into a single collection (include a discriminator field if necessary so you can tell what kind of document you have in each instance).

Run map-reduce on that collection

In Map, emit the word as the key and a value, say `{instance:1, dict:0}` or `{instance:0, dict:1}` depending on whether the document being mapped is an instance or a dictionary entry.  (You could add more fields here into the values as necessary.)

In Reduce, accumulate the scores (as usual).

Now do a query looking for `instance > 0` and `dict > 0` and you have all of the words that are in both.

Answer (score -1):

let

```
 db.word.findOne() >{ word:'a_word', ... }

 db.dict.findOne() >{ word:'a_word', def:'def_of_a_word', ... }
```

find words in word col.

```
db.word.distinct('word')
```

check if a_word exists in dict col.

```
db.dict.count({word:'a_word'})  // 0=not exist
```