# Using Underscore or lodash in Nodejs for realtime computations ? Performance?

Tags: performance, node.js, mongoose, underscore.js, lodash

I'd like to use lodash in my nodejs project mostly for pluck,intersection,zip etc.. 
I have a mongodb collection 'OnlineUsers' and it has 'params' array in it for every user(doc) .The most redundant job my app does is find intersection on params array of one user to rest of the users and find the user2 with which the user1 has most interesected params .

There might be around 500-600 OnlineUsers initially but i want it to scale upto thousands.
I dont know if aggregation framework helps making array intersections

Using underscore or lodash in realtime for finding intersections of 100 or 1000s arrays is normal ? I need the response to be less than 2s atleast .

Anyone with benchmarks(pluck and intersection) would be great

Comment: I think the biggest problem isn't in the manipulation of the arrays, but the overhead (speed and memory) of Mongo fetching all the documents from disk and sending them all over to node. If it is possible I would look into ways of keeping all this logic in the database layer.

Comment: Doing intersection on retrieved documents is not a good idea. I agree with askmike on doing this within database, you can do map-reduce on collections, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389150/finding-intersection-between-two-collections-in-mongodb

Comment: If you'll still decide to use any JS framework - pay attention to [LazyJS](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/). There're several benchmarks (with lodash and underscore as well).